# regex. Match all words starting with two letter

Tags: python, regex

I wish to find all words that start with "Am" and this is what I tried so far with python

```
import re
my_string = "America's mom, American"
re.findall(r'\b[Am][a-zA-Z]+\b', my_string)
```

but this is the output that I get

```
['America', 'mom', 'American']
```

Instead of what I want

```
['America', 'American']
```

I know that in regex `[Am]` means match either `A` or `m`, but is it possible to match `A` and `m` as well?

Comment: re.findall(r'\bAm[a-zA-Z]+\b', my_string), can you check this

Comment: drop first `[]` - `\bAm[a-zA-Z]+\b` - you want to match `Am` *literally*, `A` then `m` not a as *set* {`Am` or `mA`, `m`, `A`}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[Am]`, a positive [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), matches either `A` or `m`. To match a *sequence* of chars, you need to use them one after another.

Remove the brackets:

```
import re
my_string = "America's mom, American"
print(re.findall(r'\bAm[a-zA-Z]+\b', my_string))
# => ['America', 'American']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/saGZrG)

**This pattern details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Am` - a string of chars matched as a sequence `Am`
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use character class:

```
import re
my_string = "America's mom, American"
re.findall(r'\bAm[a-zA-Z]+\b', my_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall(r'(Am\w+)', my_text, re.I)
```

Comment: Well, that may match `Am3` and `Am_____` which might not  be what OP expects.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In that case, he just need to change `\w+` to `a-z`

Comment: Yeah, and use my solution. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yours won't work if the string is `a`merica instead of `A`merica

Comment: If OP needs a case-insensitive search, adding `re.I` will solve the issue. However, the question states that the string should *"start with "Am"*. Not *`am` or `Am`*.